# Are there local tour search websites in Colombia?

Tags: online-resources, colombia

Recently I was searching for a guided tour of Tayrona National Park near Santa Marta. English-language resources such as Viator only had tours starting from $120/person. However I was able to find a local tour for $40/person by walking into a random tour agency in Santa Marta. The cheaper tour didn't have an English-speaking guide but this wasn't a problem in my case.

While walking into random tourist agencies on the spot is certainly a valid strategy, are there any local tour search websites in Colombia where one might find tours for a fair price? I presume locals don't use websites like Viator but my Spanish-language Google-fu isn't strong enough to find alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to book something, it will become tough if you only seek an overview, [Parquesnacionales.gov.co](https://www.parquesnacionales.gov.co/portal/en/) might do the trick.

[Colombia.travel](https://colombia.travel/en) also offers a good overview of where to go and what to do. On that website, they show you official Instagram accounts of the parks and such, so you can find local links which you can book.

Ultimately, you have to hunt for the local websites on which you can make the bookings. For [Parque Tayrona](https://www.parquetayrona.com/es/tour/tour-navegando-hacia-bahia-concha/), you could have booked on the official website and saved a few compared to booking with Viator.